# Output is blank

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, calling-convention

```
def load():
    name=0
    count=0
    totalpr=0
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

def calc():
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss

def print():
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))
    print("Total Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    load()
    calc()
    print()
```

I want to write the main() function to call the functions above it.

However, when I run the program, the output is blank - nothing - there is no error given to elucidate the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're overriding the builtin `print()` function... Use a different name

Comment: I changed it. nothing still happening.

Comment: Also, you've scope problem. All those variables defined in each function are out of scope in others.

Comment: Does that mean they don't carry over the data? What should I do to fix that?

Comment: Read about scope rules here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-scoping-rules and check my answer for the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the problem of using built-in function, you've scope problem too. So, you must make the variables defined in each function `global` so that they can be assessed in other functions.

```
def load():    
    global name
    global count
    global shares
    global pp
    global sp
    global commission
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    count =0
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

def calc():
    global amount_paid
    global amount_sold
    global profit_loss
    global commission_paid_sale
    global commission_paid_purchase
    global totalpr
    totalpr=0
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss

def display():
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))
    print("Total Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    load()
    calc()
    display()

main()
```

Comment: This does not display after entering the stock information. Instead, if you enter the stock information and enter "-999" it prints the stock info with the name "-999" whereas I would like it to immediately calculate and then display after entering commission.

Answer (score 0):

To run a python module as a program, you should run it like the below one. In your program main is just like other functions and won't be executed automatically.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    load()
    calc()
    print()
```

What we are doing is, we check if the module name is `__main__` and we call other functions. `__main__` is set only when we run the module as a main program.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `main()` & also change `print()` function name, here I have changed it to `fprint()`

```
def load():
    name=0
    count=0
    totalpr=0
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

def calc():
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss

def fprint():
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))
    print("Total Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    load()
    calc()
    fprint()
main()
```

edit: changed function name of print()

Comment: Thanks! However: now, I get stuck in a loop and it won't call the print.

Comment: change the print funtion name

Comment: also the variables won't work as their scope is limited to their respective functions. Make the variables common to all

Comment: use `while name != -999:` becoz when you enter 999 then input function takes value as integer type and you are comparing with string `'-999'`